# How to invite non-friends to like your Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, notifications, facebook-like

Today I got a notification from a person I'm not friend of (although we have 22 mutual friends) to like his page.

I thought this wasn't possible. Is it a paid feature or what? I can't understand how he sent me that "like my page" notification.

Comment: Did he send it to your personal profile or to a page?  The latter didn't used to work, but recently I've found that my pages can invite other pages to become fans.

Comment: He sent the invite to like his page to my personal profile.

Answer (score 2):

When a person with admin privileges for a given page access the "Build Audience" menu in the Admin Panel:

- the "Invite Friends..." item should allow him to invite only friends (of that admin).  He should ***not*** have been able to invite you this way, if you are not a direct friend.
- the "Invite Email Contacts..." item should allow him to invite *anyone* for which he has an email address.  It is possible that *this* was used to invite you, as I assume that if the invitee has a Facebook account associated with the email address, that the invitee will receive some sort of Facebook notification (and not just a purely-email, non-FB, invite).

Answer (score -1):

Unless you disabled it, anyone can send you messages. This can be adjusted by using the “Who can contact me” section of the privacy shortcuts.